# Android Studio Package Formatting

Tags: android-studio, android-package-managers

Good day guys! I have a question about how to properly format packages (in my own words) in Android Studio. Here is the example:

I want to change this package format:

[image]

Is there a way to hide those two highlighted packages? Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two packages are used for android tests. If you don't do automated tests you can delete those.